# How to find particular table in which class in whole webApplication

Tags: java, sql

In a webApplication have 900pages java `class & jsp pages`, 920 tables,250 procedure,430 functions. now my question is that suppose that there is table `"employee_Table"` now i wanna know that in which class using this table and in which jsp page using this table, and in which procedure and also in which functions using this table.

I am working on it from 2 days but unable to get any logic so kindly help it.

Comment: Are you using Hibernate? If yes you must start by looking at the hbm files.

Comment: you can do a find string in your project files. or you can rename that table, do some updates with your application and wait for the exception stack trace.

Comment: How do you access the database? Raw JDBC or do you use a framework like Hibernate or jOOQ?

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is probably to search all the sources (Java, DDL and SQL) for the string `employee_Table` (case insensitive, please). The reasoning here is that this string is pretty unique so you won't get many unwanted search results.

The next step is to use an `enum` or create a new type `TableName` and replace all string literals with it. That way, you can now tell your IDE to search for all places where the `enum` or `TableName` constant is being used.